# Magento 2.1.5 products filter problem

Tags: category, attributes, filter

I'm currently working on setting up a **e-commerce website**. Of course we want to use a filter for the products but I'm facing a problem at the moment.

I have a **category** with **5 products**. All of them are configurable products which have different sizes. On the left of the category page I have the filters visible, but the size filter isn't showing all the sizes of the products. It's not showing sizes that are available in all of the 5 products (in my case all products have size Medium & Large, but these are not showing up in the filter). Sizes that are not available in all the 5 products do so show up, for example Extra Small & Extra Large.

I have looking around the internet for a solution but I'm having bad luck today.. Is anybody here familiar with this?